# Node.js middleware to read more than one mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am new to authentication with node.js and am struggling to implement the following:

I currently have a middleware function that checks the access token sent with the request and pulls the user relating to that token, then appends that user onto the request so I can use their details. This works completely fine for my `Users` collection, however I am wanting to add a new collection for a completely different type of user, called `Owners`.

Based on the function I currently have, I cannot seem to find a way to have it check both collections - this is my current function that works with my one `Users` collection.

```
//
// Middleware that authenticates token and appends user to request
//
module.exports.required = function (req, res, next) {
  const auth_header = req.header("authorization").split(" ");
  const auth_type = auth_header[0];
  const auth_token = auth_header[1] || null;

  // Check token
  if (auth_type !== "Bearer" || !auth_token) {
    return next(HttpError(401, "Token is invalid."));
  }

  // Find user matching access token
  return User.findOne({ access_token: auth_token })
    .orFail(HttpError(401, "Token does not exist."))
    .then((user) => {
      try {
        // Check if token has no expired
        decodeToken(auth_token);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name !== "TokenExpiredError") return next(err);

        // Refresh token
        user.generateAccessToken();

        // Save and return new user
        return user.save();
      }

      return user;
    })
    .then((user) => {
      // Append user object to the incoming request
      req.user = user;
      return next();
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

Can anyone help me understand out how I would check both collections (Users & Owners)?

Comment: did you add a reference to Owners in your Users docmunt/model?

Comment: no, theyre completely separate types of users, owners are system admins and have different schemas - would a reference be the right approach?

Comment: i guess it would depend. Two approaches come to mind, make a reference in Users so you can retrieve information from Owners or use several middleware callbacks such  express's app.use to call the appropriate functions and get data. Then write the data into a single object and send it. You could probably also do this in one function

Comment: How would the reference work? they would use different access tokens and no one 'owner' would be related to a 'user', so there would be no reference (object ID) for me to make as there is no colleration between the two?

Comment: if they have no relation, e.g a particular user cant be an owner or have owner status/priviledge, then I would think you need to query both documents separately then append the data to an empty object/hashmap if you need to send it back to client